# How can "take it as you list" mean anything like "go to hell"?

Tags: translation

This is a quote from "the Tempest" by Stephano:

> If thou beest a man, show thyself in thy likeness. If
>   thou beest a devil, take ’t as thou list.

And it was [translated](https://www.litcharts.com/shakescleare/shakespeare-translations/the-tempest/act-3-scene-2) to:

> If you’re a man who's playing that music, show yourself. If you’re a devil, then you can go to hell.

"List" here means, as a verb, to want. So I want to ask how "take it as you want" mean anything like "go to hell".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea, really.  The language of Shakespeare's time is full of odd colloquialisms and references that are lost on the modern English speaker, not to mention all the expressions Shakespeare completely made up, some of which [have become idiomatic English](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/word-lists/list-of-words-and-phrases-shakespeare-invented.html).

My best guess, however, is that "list" in this context means "do what is expected by your nature" -- which is to say, a devil should be in Hell.